# Jquery: Hide div that contains an element as descendent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `div` elements with the same class. Using jQuery, how can I set `display: none` to the `div` that contains `select#s2`?

```
<div class="demoClass">
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <select id="s1"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="demoClass">
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <select id="s2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery. Please help.

Comment: `$('.demoClass:has(#s1)').hide()`

Comment: $('#s1').parent().hide();

Comment: IDs are unique. You can select them directly.

Comment: $("#s1").parent.hide();   :) :)

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal : He wants to select the parent `div`, not the `select` element. :)

Comment: @Yuriko So, select id first then select its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#s2").parent(".innerdiv").parent(".demoClass").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="demoClass">
    <div class="innerdiv">
        Example<select id="s1"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="demoClass">
    <div class="innerdiv">
        Hello<select id="s2"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#s2").parent(".innerdiv").parent(".demoClass").hide();

// Or..

$("#s2").parent(".innerdiv").parent(".demoClass").css('display','none');
```

Comment: `.demoClass` isnt the parent of the select `.innerdiv` is the parent of select so this is wrong

Comment: Still not correct `div that contains select#s2` as per OP requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to check if an element contains another element.

```
$('.demoClass:has(#s1)').hide()
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f54a1yh8/)

```js
$('.demoClass:has(#s1)').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoClass">aaa
  <div class="innerdiv">First
    <select id="s1"></select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="demoClass">BBB
  <div class="innerdiv">Second
    <select id="s2"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f54a1yh8/3/)

```js
$("#s1").closest(".demoClass").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoClass">aaa
  <div class="innerdiv">First
    <select id="s1"></select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="demoClass">BBB
  <div class="innerdiv">Second
    <select id="s2"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

```
$("#s2").closest(".demoClass").hide();
```